# How to set Height of linerlayout through java code

Tags: android-layout

In xml file I am Using Relative layout as parent ..
In that i am using Linerlayout as child..
How can i set the height of linear layout?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code which will set the height of the linear layout.. It will correspond to the
parent ie in your case RelativeLayout.. hope it will work correctly...
`LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout0);
linearLayout .setMinimumHeight(minHeight);`